# How can you use flask to make the text of your website blue?

Tags: python, html, flask

How can you use flask to make the text of your website blue? I only know how to display text on your website. My code :

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return '''Hello world'''
```

Comment: This isn't a Flask question; it's a HTML question, and one that can be easily researched

Comment: But why does it import flask?

Comment: Because Flask is the framework that returns the template of the site or, in this case, just the string. It's the body of the string that's important, and changing the text colour would be independent of the framework returning the response

Comment: Ayush Gudipati Student I soon will answer you.Allow me some time. Yours is a good question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Despite the negative feedback from other user, this is not that bad of a question, besides apart of @go2nirvana no one answered your question.

### Note

Despite this is more a Front-end question related to CSS or Javascript and not HTML (yes you can embed  CSS inline within HTML but is not recommended) what you asked can be achieved in Flask in many ways.

> ### Example 1 -Hard coding, not recommended buy you can do it-

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():

    my_html =  '''
    
    <body style="background-color: #e1eb34;">

    
        <h1 style="color:  #002aff;">Hello World</h1>
    
    </body>
    
    ''' 
    return my_html

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

or

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return '''
    
    <body style="background-color: #e1eb34;">

    
        <h1 style="color:  #002aff;">Hello World</h1>
    
    </body>
    
    '''

if __name__ == '__main__':
```

> ### Example 2 -Using Jinja2  [DOCS](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/)##

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():

    color = {
        'blue': '002aff',
        'yellow': 'e1eb34',
        'green': '28fc03',
        'red': 'fc1703', 
        'purple': 'b503fc'}

    return render_template('index.html', color=color)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body style="background-color: #{{color['yellow']}};">

        {% for hue in color.values() if hue != 'e1eb34'%}
        
            <h1 style="color: #{{hue}};">Hello World</h1>
        {% endfor %}
        <h1></h1>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

> ### Example 3 -Adding request, session, redirect, url_for and more fun

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for, request, session
import random

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'dev'

color = {
        'blue': '002aff',
        'yellow': 'e1eb34',
        'green': '28fc03',
        'red': 'fc1703', 
        'purple': 'b503fc', 
        'orange': 'FF9733 ',
        'black' : 'FFFFFF',
        'light-blue': '0AE5E3', 
        'pink': 'FF95AE',
        'blue-green' : '95FFCA'}

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():

    error = None
    if 'color' not in session:
        session['color'] = None
        session['background'] = None

    if request.method == 'POST':        
        choice = request.form['color'].lower()
        
        if choice not in color: 
            error = 'Color not in list'
            return render_template('index.html', color=session['color'], background=session['background'], error=error )
        else:
            session['color'] = color.get(choice)
           
            session['background'] = random.choice(list(color.values()))
        return redirect(url_for('index'))

    return render_template('index.html', color=session['color'], background=session['background'], error=error )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
        
        {% if color%}
            <style>
                body {
                    color: #{{color}};
                    background-color: #{{background}};
            
            }
            </style>
        {% endif %}
        
    </head>
    <body>

        <h1>Hello World</h1>
        {% if error%}
            {{error}}
        {% endif %}
        <form action="{{url_for('index')}}" method="POST">
            <label for="color">Choose a color</label>
            <input type="text" name="color">
            <input type="submit" value="PRESSS" name="i_talk-with_flask">
        </form>
       
        
        
    </body>
</html>
```

> > Variation with  a Macro [DOC](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#macros)

```
{% macro color_mix(color)%}
    {% if color%}
        <style>
            body {color: #{{color}};}
            body {background-color: #{{background_}};}
        </style>
    {% endif %}

{% endmacro%}


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
        
        {{color_mix(color)}}
    </head>
    <body>

        <h1>Hello World</h1>
        {% if error%}
            {{error}}
        {% endif %}
        <form action="{{url_for('index')}}" method="POST">
            <label for="color">Choose a color</label>
            <input type="text" name="color">
            <input type="submit" value="PRESSS" name="i_talk-with_flask">
        </form>
       
        
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Honestly this is only the tip of the iceberg of the option you can have. Now is this reccomended ? Probably not, because this it should be handle with CSS or then handle it with JavaScript.

However there may be planty of instances where you may want to use it from a Flask App, one of there are:

- Testing Purposes.
- Debugging.
- Something related to a Database.
- Fun

Comment: Thanks, it helped. Now I have a new question, Can you use an image for the background? And if possible, can you use an image for the background without downloading the image?

Comment: I did a separate answer. This is again a HTML and CSS question, but nevertheless this is a small example of what you can do with Pictures in Flask

Answer (score 3):

That's a CSS question, not Flask.

```
return '<span style="color: #00ccff;">Hello world</span>'
```

Comment: Sorry, I was a beginner at HTML, flask, CSS, js when I asked the question, but now I understand.

Comment: I think what @AyushGudipati asked is, can you dynamically change the color, based on some outside variable.  Which you can't do, with just CSS.

Answer (score 1):

### Answer to Question 2

I'm assuming that you mean taking an image from the web. Yes you can, but this is definitely a CSS/HTML related question. However following the same principle of my previous answer:

> **Picures taken from [Unsplash](https://unsplash.com/)**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():

    my_pic = 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1469980098053-382eb10ba017?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80'
    return render_template('index.html', my_pic=my_pic)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body style="background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1600187734183-707cf1c0fd5a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1304&q=80);"
> 
   
    <  <div>

            <h1 style="color: white;">Picture from HTML</h1>
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1600298881979-9b0c50d7abdf?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=400&q=60" alt="opps">
        </div>


    <div style="color: white;">
        <h1>Picture from Flask</h1>
        <img src="{{my_pic}}" alt="oops">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I suggest you to learn it from HTML and CSS related topic rather than Flask (first learn some CSS and HTML basic):

- [CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp)
- [HTML](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp)

That been said I have a more interesting a USEFUL answer that however requires basic knowledge of the use of a Database, I assume you are a beginner and you may have not yet this knowledge but soon or later you will. So even if you dont understand completely the following keep it in mind and come back later.

I prepared a mini app that using flask, flask_sqlalchemy (with sqlite3), html and Bootstrap.

This app does the following and will teach you these principle:

.1 Upload a picture into a Database.
.2 How to download a picture from the Database.
.3 Render the picture from the Database into the WebBroser.

### [FULL CODE FROM GITHUB](https://github.com/Koubae/flask-app-upload)

---

### Some Code from this mini app

---

## Initiate the database, configs and Picture table for the databse

> > In class FileContent(db.Model):

- data = file.read()  It saves in database the Binary version of thefile
  -render_file = render_picture(data).  It saves the decode version, so that you can you see it for render it in the webpages.

  ```
    # Built-in Imports
    import os
    from datetime import datetime
    from base64 import b64encode
    import base64
    from io import BytesIO #Converts data from Database into bytes

    # Flask
    from flask import Flask, render_template, request, flash, redirect, url_for, send_file # Converst bytes into a file for downloads

    # FLask SQLAlchemy, Database
    from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy


    basedir = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), 'data.sqlite')

    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = basedir
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'dev'
    db = SQLAlchemy(app)

    # Picture table. By default the table name is filecontent
    class FileContent(db.Model):

        """ 
        The first time the app runs you need to create the table. In Python
        terminal import db, Then run db.create_all()
        """
        """ ___tablename__ = 'yourchoice' """ # You can override the default table name

        id = db.Column(db.Integer,  primary_key=True)
        name = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=False)
        data = db.Column(db.LargeBinary, nullable=False) #Actual data, needed for Download
        rendered_data = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)#Data to render the pic in browser
        text = db.Column(db.Text)
        location = db.Column(db.String(64))
        pic_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
        def __repr__(self):
            return f'Pic Name: {self.name} Data: {self.data} text: {self.text} created on: {self.pic_date} location: {self.location}'
  ```

### Upload route, here is where the picture its sent to databse and processed with correct data

> > So here is what is going on in the app route:

- def render_picture(data)  --> Takes the bites raw version of the pic and return the decode version, so that it can be used to be display on the web.
- data = file.read() : This is the raw data.This can be used for downloading the pic from database
- render_file: decoded file so you can retrieve it and the render in the web page

  #Render the pics, this Function converts the data from
  request.files['inputFile'] so that in can be displayed

  ```
  def render_picture(data):

      render_pic = base64.b64encode(data).decode('ascii') 
      return render_pic


  @app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
  def upload():

     file = request.files['inputFile']
     data = file.read()
     render_file = render_picture(data)
     text = request.form['text']
     location = request.form['location']

     newFile = FileContent(name=file.filename, data=data, 
     rendered_data=render_file, text=text, location=location)
     db.session.add(newFile)
     db.session.commit() 
     flash(f'Pic {newFile.name} uploaded Text: {newFile.text} Location: 
     {newFile.location}')

     return render_template('upload.html')
  ```

### INDEX Route

```
# Index It routes to index.html where the upload forms is 
@app.route('/index', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/')
def index():

    return render_template('index.html')
```

### INDEX HTML with the Form

```
<form method="POST" action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <!-- File Upload-->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputFile">File input</label>
            <input class="form-control-file" type="file" name="inputFile">
        </div>

        <!-- Location -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="location">Location</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="location">
        </div>

        <!-- Text -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="text">Write Text</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" name="text" id="text" rows="5" placeholder="Add a Description"></textarea>
        </div>

        <!-- Submit -->        
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
```